# How to format number using format-number in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to format float number in xslt? I know that I should use this function format-number, but don't really know.

example:
047.6000 to 47.60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You may use like this.
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'#.00')"/>
```